# Howto insert correctly in MYSQL with multiple foreach

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, foreach

I have one small problem....I dont know how to correct INSERT all my data in table, I try to explane. For example I have 2 system_ids(1006,1011) and 5 ids (1,3,4,19,18) to insert in each system, for example :

```
=======================================
  system_id | attribute_id | term_id
=======================================
    1006           1            29
    1006           3            29
    1006           4            29
    1006           19           29
    1006           18           29
    1011           1            29
    1011           3            29
    1011           4            29
    1011           19           29
    1011           18           29
```

I have tried something like this, but this not working how I need...

```
          foreach ($sistemu_ids as $sistemos) {
            foreach ($rez as $rezas) {
              $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO " . $wpdb->prefix . "My_table
(system_id, attribute_id,term_id) VALUES ('$sistemos', '$rezas', '29')");
            }
          }
```

This code inserts like this:

```
=======================================
  system_id | attribute_id | term_id
=======================================
    1006           1            29
    1006           3            29
    1006           4            29
    1006           19           29
    1006           18           29
                   1            29
                   3            29
                   4            29
                   19           29
                   18           29
```

Comment: your code seems to be fine. what is a problem?

Comment: test your input data because - https://eval.in/547335

Comment: Try to `print_r` you input data and check if `$sistemu_ids` contains both values

Comment: Thanks, problem is in $sistemu_ids Array :-))

Comment: $sistemu_ids probably contains an empty string or a null value in the array generating the second interation with the empty system_id. To solve clean the array first or don't interate over invalid values.

Comment: Yes you right, second system_id array was empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Mytable (system_id, attribute_id,term_id) VALUES ";
foreach ($sistemu_ids as $key => $sistemos) {
    foreach ($rez as $rezas) {
        $queryValues[] = "('$sistemos','$rezas',29)";
    }
}
$query .= implode(',',$queryValues);
$wpdb->query($query);
```

Store values into an array and than execute your queries for multiple records like:

```
INSERT INTO table (col,...) VALUES (val1,..),(val1,...)
```

Comment: This is definitely a better and faster approach, but doesn't solve his issue.